# How to hide rows in DatagridView starting from row with index 2 and till the end?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void HideRows(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    IndexRows = RowIndex;

    if (IndexRows>2)
    {
        DataGridView.Rows[IndexRows].Visible=false;
    }
    else
    {
        DataGridView.Rows[IndexRows].Visible=true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to understand what all other details you need to add in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    // Avoid for Row which are currently in Edit mode
    if (!row.IsNewRow)
    {
        row.Visible = row.Index < 2;
    }
}
```